# ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How I can solve this problem?
I work on :
Pycharm
python 3.6
keras 2.4.3

I try many times to install tensorflow but the install is failed in each time.

This error when I running:
`ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via pip install tensorflow`

This error when I try to install the tensorflow:

[image]

Comment: You should consider that we cannot help you if you do not provide enough information in your question, errors and difficulties need to be put in detail.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to install tensorflow?

Comment: Are you installing through pycharm, or the command line?

Comment: I install through pycharm , from setting >>python Intrtpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do what it says, and run it from the command line. `pip install tensorflow`. But the problem is that you are not using the latest version of pip. Use `python -m pip install –upgrade pip`. Then re-run everything. All from the command line. And check that you are using the same python interpreter.

Comment: You can also specify a version to install with `pip install tensorflow==2.2`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to do with how you have environments set up in Pycharm. I would try what they are suggesting: try installing from the terminal (using the same environment). Better yet, create a new environment and install everything at the same time (i.e. Tensorflow, Keras)